# postgresql, Insert data into dynamically created table

Tags: java, postgresql, triggers

I have to copy data from one table(main_tbl) to another table(sub_tbl)

```
CREATE  OR  REPLACE FUNCTION  auditlogfunc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS  
$example_table$
DECLARE 
  temp text;
BEGIN
    temp = 'SELECT device_id FROM company ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
    INSERT INTO temp(emp_id, entry_date, name,age)      VALUES(new.id,current_timestamp,  new.name, new.age);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$example_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`temp = 'SELECT device_id FROM company ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';` this will select the last value from main_tbl and stored into temp variable.

Now I want to copy data from main_tbl to temp table..

> ERROR:  relation "temp" does not exist

Comment: "*this will select the last value from main_tbl and stored into temp variable*"  no it will not. It will store the string `'SELECT device_id FROM company ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';` into the variable `temp`. You want `select device_id into temp from ...`https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW You also need to create the table `temp` before you can insert into it

Comment: But temp is just a variable to store the result..

Comment: Exactly. So how do you expect that to be a table?

Comment: I want to insert the data into value inside temp variable... e.g. if select query return result dv0002  and it is stored int temp variable.. dv0002 table is already present in DB.. My problem is that how I define dv0002 in query because it is the value contain in temp variable..

Comment: First (as I already said): you are **not** storing a value from the database into that variable. To do what you want you need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this post is not giving me answer. Actually if i tried to execute INSERT INTO dv0002(emp_id, entry_date, name,age)      VALUES(new.id,current_timestamp,  new.name, new.age); This will executed. but this table name is getting me at run time, at the same time i have to store data also in that table.

Comment: Again: you need dynamic SQL for that. How you do that is explained in the manual:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+dynamic-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@a_horse_with_no_name has already pointed out how to do this. If i understood correctly, you dv002 table is already created.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  auditlogfunc ()
 RETURNS trigger AS
 $body$ 

DECLARE 
  get_last_value integer;
  your_table_name text := 'dv002';
BEGIN

  SELECT id into get_last_value FROM tb_main_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
  EXECUTE format('insert into %s(emp_id, entry_date, name,age) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)', your_table_name) using get_last_value,new.id,current_timestamp,  new.name, new.age;

 RETURN new;
 $body$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) how to store the result of a query in a variable.

See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) how to execute a string as an SQL command.

Use the `quote_ident()` function on the variable before including it as identifier in an SQL query string. That way you are safe from SQL injection.